# How to update SharePoint Content Type?

Tags: sharepoint, deployment

I need to update an existing SharePoint content type by adding a new field to the content type.  I need to make sure this field gets added to all lists that use this content type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your content type was created using a Feature, as far as I know, you can't upgrade the Feature to add the new column to the content type.

That leaves you with two options:

1. Do it in the UI
2. Do it programmatically using the SharePoint object model

Here's an example of doing option #2: http://blogs.msdn.com/nidhishd/archive/2008/05/06/how-to-modify-content-type-once-it-is-deployed.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is really out of the box, standard functionality.  When you edit a content type, adding a field, it gets added to all the instances where that content type is used.

Each new entry in that list will include the updated field.  Any existing entry will have that field as well, but it will be empty.

Comment: What if I edit something generic, like "folder", which isn't selectable in the content types list?

Answer (score 0):

If you make updates only (by adding field) you should be able to do this.

```
STSADM -deactivefeature...
STSADM -installfeature... (contenttype with new field)
STSADM -activatefeature...
IISRESET
```

you should now se your new fields ind the contenttypes gallery, but you-ll need to remove/add the contenttype to the desired lists before they will appear